# Object rotating in a circle without rope

Tags: centripetal-force

An object is rotating in a vertical circle. There is no aid, ie no rope. So how does the object keep moving in the circle? Is it the normal force that provides the centripetal force? Also can friction too provide centripetal force in case of a vertical circle ( I assume not ?). I don’t get how the normal force would change with respect to positions in the circle.

Comment: If there is "no aid" then where does the normal force come from?

Answer (score 1):

Centripetal force is always directed radially, i.e., it should be normal to the trajectory of an object moving around a circle.

If so, normal reaction, which is also normal to the trajectory of an object, naturally acts as a centripetal force. As an object moves around a circle, vertical or not, the normal reaction, as a hand of a clock, is constantly changing its direction.

Friction force, on the other hand, is tangent to the trajectory of an object and, therefore, does not contribute to a centripetal force.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the normal force would act as the centripetal force in this case. As for your last question, assuming the object is going at a constant tangential velocity, the normal force will not change.

However, there's still another force that hasn't been accounted for, yet: gravity. So why won't the object fall (assuming it keeps going around the circle)? 
It is because there is a frictional force pointing away from gravity (and that friction force arises because there is a normal force applied to the object).

Sometimes, however, friction can act as a centripetal force (but not in your example, as friction is perpendicular to the radius). For example, when a car turns around a curve, the friction from the tires keep it on the road, and prevent it from flying out.

Comment: Oh yes ok, but wouldn’t the normal force at the bottom the circle be larger than at top, because the weight is always downwards?